# WPF two-way binding not updated from UI

Tags: c#, wpf

When the model is updated, the UI is updated accordingly, but when I update the textbox that has two-way binding, the setter in the view-model is not called. What am I doing wrong?

Here is how view-model is bound to view

```
public partial class MyView : MetroWindow
{
    public MyView()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MyViewModel(new DialogService(this));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SelectedEntity.Prop1, >Mode=TwoWay}"
controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
controls:TextBoxHelper.IsWaitingForData="True"
controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True"
controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{x:Static >properties:Resources.Prop1}" />
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SelectedEntity.Prop2}"
controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
controls:TextBoxHelper.IsWaitingForData="True"
controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True"
controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{x:Static >properties:Resources.Prop2}"/>
```

The view-model

```
public class MyViewModel : IMyViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{

   private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private readonly MyModel _model;
    private MyEntity _selectedEntity;

public MyViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
{
    _dialogService = dialogService;

    _selectedEntity = new MyEntity();
    _model = new MyModel();
    _model.PropertyChanged += _model_PropertyChanged;
}

public MyEntity SelectedEntity 
{
    get
    {
            var information = _model.GetInformation();
            _selectedEntity.Flight = information.Prop1;
            information.Destination = information.Prop2;
            return _selectedEntity;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedEntity = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEntity");
    } 
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new          PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

 }
```

Comment: which setter are you inspecting `SelectedEntity` or `Prop1` or `Prop2`?

Comment: I do not know if you noticed but you have got an error in your code {Binding SelectedEntity.Prop1, >Mode=TwoWay}" - pay attention to the '>'. Also near properties

Comment: I am inspecting SelectedEntity, which again have Prop1 and Prop2, the setter for SelectedEntity is not called though when updating the textbox bound to SelectedEntity.Prop1 from UI.

Comment: Adding a string property SelectedProp1 in the MyViewModel and binding to that instead of the SelectedEntity.Prop1 works. Then the setter for that property is called. I thought it should be possible to just have one property for the entity-class.

Comment: @user1041481 "I am inspecting SelectedEntity", that's your problem, it's not the setter of "SelectedEntity" that will be called but that og "Prop1"

Answer (score 4):

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SelectedEntity.Prop1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

The Default UpdateSourceTrigger for TextBox is LostFocus I believe, so you need to explicitly set it to PropertyChanged. This way it will fire whenever the property changes.

Comment: Also, using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged may still not work depending on which framework you use and what you do in the bound property's setter, you may hit this wall: https://sparethought.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/binding-to-wpf-textbox-seems-to-be-broken-in-net-4-5-beta/ (workaround: FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;) because in 4.5 they "fixed" a bug and the fix is in some ways wors than the bug itself...

Comment: Using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged does not help

Comment: @user1041481 Did you remove the '>' before "Mode=TwoWay" ?

Comment: Yes, that was introduced in my post, but not part of the code. I am getting binding to work from view to viewmodel when binding is done to a string property for each textbox, but not when bound to a string property in a class.

Comment: @user1041481 Well, I don't know what could be going wrong. It looks like it should work. I recommend starting from scratch with just a textbox bound to a viewmodel containing only a string ant then bit by bit adding stuff from your main project until it stops working, then you'll know what caused the issue. You could also update your post to include your "MyEntity " class so we can look at it.

Comment: @Tesseract Good idea. I'll clean up and see if I can find out which step it starts to go wrong. The "MyEntity" class is a plain entity-class with properties (public string Prop1 { get; set; })

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` **solved** my issue. Before this modifications, I had to press TAB in order to update the data source passing `TextBox`'s value for this purpose.

Comment: Mother of GOD I want the whole LostFocus event to be gone for good. It being the default for stuff like this is wild to me.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, even twoway binding isn't sufficient. It seems, binder instance's setter isn't called when you update the value from binded instance, even if you succeed in assigning the old value with new value.  You need to set PropertyChangedCallback callback of the Dependency Property during declaration to capture this change.

details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback?view=netframework-4.8